# Как избавиться от лагов? C# Unity2d

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, оптимизация, unity3d

Делал небольшую 2д игрушку,рпг с видом top-down.
Друг рисовал для меня спрайты, я занимался всем остальным.
Спрайты, насколько я помню, были около 5кб весом +-

Я насоздавал кучу скриптов, наследующихся от mono-behaviour для каждого объекта, где в апдейте прописывал в основном их движение, и что-то ,что требовало постоянность выполнения (тоесть как мне казажется, использовал по назначению).

В ходе разработки игры не возникало проблем, пока дело не дошло до врагов. Когда у меня на сцене находилось более 3 врагов, которые следовали за мной - то у меня происходили жуткие провисания.

Суть вопроса: что могло привести к таким провисаним? Над чем мне нужно работать, чтобы такого не происходило?

В данный момент я нашел решение путем ограничения количества врагов на сцене и увеличением сложности. Из-за этого мне пришлось изменить полностью концепцию игры, что я считаю достаточно плохим решением.

Upd:
Объекты врагов были нагружены также несколькими объектами, коллайдерами, некоторые из них также имели свои скрипты. Из-за этого также могут появиться провисания?,

Comment: без кода тебе никто не скажет в чем проблема твоего кода. Для начала поищи информацию как пользоваться профайлером.

Comment: Старался задать вопрос общий, чтобы получить направление для того чтобы я понял проблему, вот вы например уже открыли для меня новое слово "профайлер", спасибо))

Comment: Общий ответ: контроллируйте, сколько времени выполняются методы `Update()` в скриптах. А так же [Профилирование процессора](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerCPU.html) поможет.